# Is OpenCR available to buy?

Tags: ros, turtlebot3, opencr

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The OpenCR board on my TurtleBot3 has stopped working. Is it possible to buy a replacement? If so, from where?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/275221/is-opencr-available-to-buy?/) by [decod](https://answers.ros.org/users/32214/decod/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2017-11-07

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can get OpenCR from the address below.
Since last month, parts of TurtleBot3 have begun to be sold separately and soon there will be more shops that can be bought through branches and agencies.

http://www.robotis.us/opencr1-0/

http://www.robotis-shop-en.com/?act=shop_en.goods_view&GS=3289

---

Originally posted by [Pyo](https://answers.ros.org/users/632/pyo/) with karma: 358 on 2017-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3